# Sidebar Category List Issue

Tags: category, sidebar

I have some code that I'm using to show Categories and Sub-Categories in my Magento webstore. Currently, each category is listed with the amount of products within that category displayed. Eg:

**Shop** (parent category)

- Category 1 (12)
- Category 2 (3)
- Category 3 (0)
- Category 4 (50)

The issue I'm having is that the product amounts when in the 'Shop' category are all correct. However, when I visit a child category (EG. Category 2), the product amounts now show all the disabled products as well. EG:

Shop (parent category)

- Category 1 (16)
- **Category 2 (5)**
- Category 3 (1)
- Category 4 (52)

The code I am using for the sidebar category list is as follows:

```
<div class="block">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><span>Categories</span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
    <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
        <dt><a class="shop-link" href="/shop.html"><?php echo $this->__('Shop') ?></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ol>
            <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
</div>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `getProductCount` method does not exclude the disabled products.
You can take a look at it in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::getProductCount()`.

You can try this instead of `$category->getProductCount()`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
          ->addCategoryFilter($category);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

$count = $collection->count();
```

Then you can use the `$count` variable in your code.

Comment: Like so? < ? php echo $count; ? >

Comment: Yes. Like that.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when using the above code. "Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/sirenvisual/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 719". Any ideas?